# Passing query param to api in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs, typescript

I have a child component, in which, after button press it pass a form field to a father component. I have to pass this fields as query Params to an `API GET /valuation/` that require more or less 20 optional parameters, in which the name differs from Input fields.

I created a temporary object `res` inside the father function accept in which I iterate the field . Still I can't figure how to pass this parameter inside the object `res`, using multiple `if` is dirty code.

for example
Function in father component

```
    accept(form:any){
        const req: any = {};
        if(form.name)
          req.user = form.name
        if(form.address)
          req.clusterAddress = form.address
       ... and so on x 20 times

this.requestService.getRequest(req).subscribe(
      (response) => {
        this.getRequest(response);
      }, (error) => {
        console.error(error);
      }
      }
```

As you can see this is not a viable option, what I can use to take dynamically the query param names?

Comment: Your question contains lots of unnecessary information. What you want to do, is to remove falsy values from a JavaScript object. The question isn't related to query params, HTTP requests, Angular, AngularJS and TypeScript. Please simplify your question.

Comment: Forgive me but I don't understand your answer, nor what are the unnecessary informations. I have to pass it to a service in which it gets those possible 20 parameters. Ok to remove falsy values from form, but how can I assign the fields, if the names doesn't match the ones in form? I have to assign singularly one by one? That's basically my question.

Comment: You can use a map... make another object that holds the information about which property from the `form` object maps to which property on the `res` object. Iterate through the keys of this object, make your falsy check and assign :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a *map* to store information about which property from the form maps to which property on your `res` object and then iterate through the keys, check for the presence of the value and assign:

```
const formToResMap: { [key: string]: string } = {
  name: 'name',
  address: 'clusterAddress',
  // ...
};

accept(form: any) {
  const req = Object.keys(formToResMap).reduce((acc, key) => {
    if (form[key]) {
      acc[formToResMap[key]] = form[key];
    }
    return acc;
  }, {});
  console.log(req);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think that's the correct way!